# Can't compile C++ program

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, terminal

Here's the code....

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    cout << "WELCOME TO C++ PROGRAMMING";
    return 0;
}
```

And when I go the terminal and pass the command..

```
g++ hello.cpp
```

It shows...

```
hello.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
hello.cpp:4:2: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope
  cout << "WELCOME TO C++ PROGRAMMING";
  ^
hello.cpp:4:2: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from hello.cpp:1:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:61:18: note:   ‘std::cout’
   extern ostream cout;  /// Linked to standard output
```

So what's the reason? And what should I do?

Comment: It is called `std::cout`.

Comment: __Your code clearly does not produce the error in your question!__ Note that the string in the error is not found anywhere in your code.

Comment: `So what's the reason? And what should I do?`  Probably quit reading old C++ books from the late 80's or early 90's.

Comment: Better read this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: Some answers advise you to use `using namespace std;`.  **DONT** use it. Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) why you shouldn't, or save this link to read once you can understand the answers.

Comment: __Your code _still_ clearly does not produce the error in your question!__ Note that the string is on line 5, while your error says that it is on line 4. I really __really__ dislike it when people post error messages from some other piece of code.

Answer (score 8):

[`cout`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) is found in the `std` namespace.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Welcome";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To avoid name collisions, the C++ library is included in a **namespace**, named `std`. So to get your program to compile, either you add:

```
using namespace std;
```

at the top of your program, either you prefix each "object" of the standard library with `std::`:

```
std::cout << "Welcome";
```

Comment: Please don't give that `using namespace std` bad advice to beginners.

Comment: Even then why is "Welcome" not printed?

Comment: @juanchopanza I agree on the bottom line, but, well, we all started by doing this, didn't we ? And by gaining experience, we slowly learned that it's in fact a bad idea. But from experience, learning c++ is already hard enough, so lets let them do that.

Comment: But not in the terminal!

Comment: @Myni Change it to `std::cout << "Welcome" << std::endl;`. The `std::endl` has the side effect of flushing your input ( or output depending on where you look from ). Since your program exits shortly after so it should be printed anyway, but I don't know what environment you run your executable in. Give it a try.

Comment: @Myni Mmm, let me guess: Windows, I assume ? The console probably gets closed before you can see anything. Try to run it from the command line.

Comment: I don't have to. I don't tell beginners to write things like `using namespace std`.

Comment: I use Deepin 2014.3 not Windows! So I run in Deepin's Terminal.

Comment: @juanchopanza oh, and most of them will not become professional programmers anyway, so while I fully agree with the issues [raised here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721), they'll never get close to the issues described. And for those who will get deeper, they will have time learning good practices.

Comment: @Myni So have you tried what I told you in my comment ... ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use std before cout

Answer (score 0):

You should have:

```
std::cout << "Welcome";
```

Comment: But still why isn't "Welcome" printed?

Comment: I just noticed that you have another problem....you have "Welcome" in the code and you get error with "WELCOME TO C++ PROGRAMMING"... are you sure you save your files before re-compiling?